# Sending questioners to other sites

Tags: discussion, off-topic

If I know that an off-topic question can be answered on a third party website/board, is it OK to send the Asker there?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it is.

If something is explicitly off-topic on Stack Exchange, there is no harm in sending the asker elsewhere.

However, do not use this for self-promotion. Do not promote a forum of your own this way.

People usually mention other sites in comments, rather than answers.

And, of  course, if something is on-topic on another Stack Exchange site than it is posted on, by all means flag to migrate, and leave a comment for the asker.

Comment: 'there is no harm in sending the asker elsewhere' well...  'I need an answer off the net, but I can't be bothered to find a good place to look/ask... I know!  I'll post it on SE and some drone will find a good place for me!  While I'm waiting for my slaves, is the bar open yet?'   It's a bad idea give any kind of impression that we do research for free - the vamps will latch on immediately.   Try very hard to not attract any more crap - there is no shortage as it is;(